# Know if a record exists

Tags: database, sqlite, vbscript

I'm writing a VBS program which interacts with an SQLite database, but I have a problem when I want to know if a record exists.

Here my code:

```vb
Dim objConn, objRecordSet, following, today, found, search_value, rst

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3

Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Database connection    
objConn.Open("DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=C:\Users\Quentin\Downloads\Quentin-Classementhashtags.db")

following = "youyou"
today = "CURRENT_DATE"

'Search if a record exists
Set rst = objRecordSet.Open "SELECT Name FROM Test WHERE Name = " & "'" & _
          following & "'" & ";", objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

If (rst.EOF) Then
    search_value = 0
Else
    search_value = 1
End If

objRecordSet.Close

'If the record doesn't exist, insert the value of the variable "following"
If search_value = 0 Then
    objRecordSet.Open "INSERT INTO Test (Name, Joined) VALUES " & "('" & _
        following & "', " & today & ");", objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
End If

objConn.Close
```

My INSERT query works when I test it without condition.

However, I have a problem line:

```vb
Set rst = objRecordSet.Open "SELECT Name FROM Test WHERE Name = " & "'" & _
          following & "'" & ";", objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

> End of expected instruction

I do that because I want to recover the result of this query in a variable. If the record exists, nothing happens (`search_value = 1`). Else insert the value of the variable `following`.

PS: [The link which I used for SQL queries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.04.heyscriptingguy.aspx).

Comment: That article is from 2008 and shows some pretty poor code practice. If you were using VBScript in something like Classic ASP where it is exposed to the internet I would seriously consider using `ADODB.Command` instead of this with parameterised queries.

Comment: Sure, but this works for me so...

Comment: Famous last words ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the query to the database, it stores the results in the recordset object directly. So for example:

```vb
objRecordSet.Open "Select * from Table", objConn
```

This would store all results in `objRecordSet`.

Now lets look at your code:

```vb
Dim objConn, objRecordSet, following, today, found, search_value, rst

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3

Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Database connection    
objConn.Open("DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=C:\Users\Quentin\Downloads\Quentin-Classementhashtags.db")

following = "youyou"
today = "CURRENT_DATE"

'Search if a record exists - Old Version
'Set rst = objRecordSet.Open "SELECT Name FROM Test WHERE Name = '" & _
'          following & "';", objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

'Search if a record exists - New Version
objRecordSet.Open "SELECT Name FROM Test WHERE Name = '" & _
    following & "';", objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

If (objRecordset.EOF) Then
    search_value = 0
Else
    search_value = 1
End If

objRecordSet.Close

'If the record doesn't exist, insert the value of the variable "following"
If search_value = 0 Then
    objRecordSet.Open "INSERT INTO Test (Name, Joined) VALUES " & "('" & _
        following & "', " & today & ");", objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
End If

objConn.Close
```

Give that a shot and let me know.